# Can't see the variables value when i standing on the variable on debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010

using VS2010. 
I don't know why this happened but suddenly i don't see the variable values when i stand with the mouse on the some variable in debug ( when the breakpoint stops )

Someone can help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be some dumb little UI bug. Try putting the variable on a watch list (right-click it). If that doesn't work, it could be that the debugging information for that symbol hasn't been generated -- it can be difficult to do so in some circumstances.